# how to judge whether a macro function is defined or not?

Tags: c, macros

Here is a header file,

```
// a.h

#ifndef _A_H_
#define _A_H_

#ifndef MACRO_FUNC
#define MACRO_FUNC(X, Y) (X * Y + X - Y)
#endif

#endif
```

The above code is how I judge whether macro function `MACRO_FUNC` is defined or not. Is that the right way to go?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` are the correct ways to test for a macro being defined.  Note that you can also use `#undef` followed by `#define` to replace any existing definition.

```
#ifdef MACRO_FUNC
#undef MACRO_FUNC
#endif
#define MACRO_FUNC(X, Y) (X * Y + X - Y)
```

Also, your sample macro would be better expressed as

```
#define MACRO_FUNC((X), (Y)) ((X) * (Y) + (X) - (Y))
```

Consider what'd happen if you called `MACRO_FUNC(somevar - 1, othervar + 1)` if the reasons for this aren't clear.

Comment: If I want to `undef` more than just one macros, can I write them in one line, I mean this `#undef MACRO_1 MACRO_2`?

Comment: No, you have to write each one on a separate line.

Comment: @ThomasH, thanks. So I can't do this (`#ifndef MACRO_1 MACRO_2`)  either?

Comment: @Alcott, no, but you can do: #if !defined(MACRO_1) && !defined(MACRO_2)

Comment: @Alcott I expect the macro in your question was just an example but I've updated my answer with an improvement to it just in case

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is the correct way to do it. Another way to ensure your own implementation is used is to undefine any previous definition first:

```
#ifdef MACRO_FUNC
#  undef MACRO_FUNC
#endif
#define MACRO_FUNC(X, Y) (X * Y + X - Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way what you did

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Since macros are evaluated by the pre-processor you need to use pre-processor directives `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` to check whether one exists.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is how you check if the macro is already defined or not.

Notice that identifiers starting with `_[A-Z]` are reserved for the implementation. Change `_A_H_` with `A_H_` for example.